# Error using VR, wrong Gooogle RV services version

Tags: augmented-reality, compatibility, aframe, virtual-reality

I'm Matias from Argentina.

I created a webpage with an A-Frame scene that works fine on desktop and mobile. However, when I try to use the VR option on mobile, i´m askedto install "Google VR services". I tap OK and it take me to Google PlayStore, where I get the following message:

"*This version is not compatible with your device*" (Samsung J7)
"*The Android version is too new for this application*" - something similar - (Samsung A32).

The same thing happens if I go to, for example, https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/. So I think its not an error on my code.

**However**, if I go to: https://apps.npr.org/rockymountain-vr/ (a page featured in the A-Frame showcase), the VR experience works correctly without even needing to install anything.

What should I do to make it work that way?

I don´t include a sample of my code as the same thing happens in aframe/example, as stated above.

**Thank you for your attention** and please let me know if I didnt express myself clearly.

Comment: That page is using 0.2.0 version... So it`s the version...